# JavaScript cuts a long numeric value while using blob constructor

Tags: javascript, parsing, long-integer

I've got a http response, it contains response.data, there's a lot long-integers. When I try to create a blob resource with the data in a following way:

```
var blob = new Blob([ response.data ], {
   type : response.headers('Content-Type')
});
```

The data is parsed and the numbers are treated as integers, the last 4 digits are getting cut (replaced by 0s) because of how JavaScript processes numbers. When I add a letter to the number e.g. "823758273883758237857823758x" it is treated as a string and processed properly.

How can I force JS to treat the numbers as strings and not as integers without adding any needless letters to them?

EDIT: Example response.data content:

"sep="x","Time","Id","Name","1234512345123451234""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON, string is always come with double quote around the content.
Like "123" will be parsed as String and 123 will be parsed as number. 
So I think the root problem is in your data source. Try to convert number as string when you generate the JSON string.

Comment: *always come with single/double quote* I believe this is incorrect. Only double quotes are allowed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Just checked the standard. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// number
a = '823758273883758237857823758';
console.log(a, JSON.parse(a));

// string
b = '"823758273883758237857823758"';
console.log(b, JSON.parse(b));

// error
c = '823758273883758237857823758x';
console.log(c, JSON.parse(c));
```

A number is not a string. A number value (not in quotes) will be parsed as the JavaScript number. A string value (in quotes) will be parsed as a string. A string does not need a random character to keep it as a string; but a number with a random character will not make it into a string, but will trigger a parse error.

If this is unsatisfactory, please show more details, including the contents of `response.data`, and/or the code that generates it.

Comment: example content of response.data: "sep="x","Time","Id","Name","1234512345123451234"
if it is indeed an integer, is there a way to convert it into a string while it is in this form?

Comment: That is invalid JSON. To start with, you have an odd number of quotes. It is so severely mangled that I can't even begin to guess what you meant. Is it an array? Is it one response or five? Is the `=` inside the string, or is it a badly represented attempt at a JSON object (where one would need to use `:`)?

Comment: This might not be json, I assumed it is because the code(it is not mine, and I can't really post it here) says so, but clearly it is not. This is just the data that is being turned into a blob resource.

Comment: this is a simple http request, and the reason this is happening is the creation of blob using blob constructor, can I somehow manipulate the data string to make the longs into strings?

Comment: Not unless you tell us how you're parsing it. I have assumed you are parsing with plain `JSON.parse`, but since what you posted isn't valid JSON, I can't tell you anything. It's like you going to a car shop and saying "my car doesn't work, sell me something to make it run" while having no knowledge not only of which part is broken, not only what model the car is; but even whether it is actually a car at all, or possibly a custom-made skateboard.

Answer (score 0):

you can try String(theNumber)

I don't know where the number is coming from, but you can also force it to be string first, before actually sending it.

I've tried:

`JSON.stringify(123)` and `JSON.stringify(String(123))`

and its result:

123

"123"

, respectively.

Comment: can I somehow turn it into is a string after it is sent? (I've updated the question, its not JSON, its just a http request string, added the response.data example)

Comment: i believe you can use String(theNumber), if you do, String(theNumber) === theNumber, it won't be equal because of the type. The other is string and the other is number.